# sum of marked Poisson variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I would like to calculate the expected value of the sum of $N+1$ (assume $N$ is large) marked Poisson variables $X$ with intensity $\lambda$ over subset $I$:
$$
S=\left\langle\sum_{i \in I} X_i\right\rangle
$$
where in subset $I$  we count only variables larger than some threshold $\alpha$: $X >\alpha$ and don't count $k$ numbers following after occurrence of any "event": $X >\alpha$.

For example in order to illustrate the subset $I$ selection rule, let's take an array of 7 Poisson variables with intensity $\lambda=5$:  $Y= [5\    11\     7\     5\     2\     3\    2]$ and $\alpha=4$ and $k=2$.
In this case, the sum S is $S=X_0+X_3=5+5=10$. We don't count elements $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_4$, $X_5$ because they occur after "the events" $X_0>\alpha$ and $X_3>\alpha$, and $X_6$ because $X_6<\alpha$.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want $N$ variables, you want $i=1$ to $N$, not $i=0$ to $N$. It's not clear what you mean "where I count only variables larger than...." Do you mean you don't include the smaller $X_i$ in the sum, or do you mean something else?

Comment: 1. You are right. we have N+1 variables but let's assume N is large.         I don't include $X \le \alpha$ in the sum.

Comment: In that case, you really shouldn't write it as a $\sum$ notation at all, since $\sum_{i=1}^N$ isn't an expression you can clarify later with text - it means a very specific thing.

Comment: this the most economic way to formulate the problem. The use of the theta functions here makes it even more obscure. It is not clear to me how to formalize the second condition (don't count k numbers following after occurrence of any "event": X>α)

Comment: I think @ThomasAndrews is right. You shouldn't use $\sum$ in this way as it has a very specific meaning. You could try, e.g., $\sum^N_{i\in I}$, and define $I$ underneath in words.

Comment: I tried & failed to make a correction to your last para where you talk about the sum $S$ but mean the expectation $<S>$: the text should read "In this case, the expectation of the sum S is $<S>=<X0+X3>=5+5=10$", in my opinion. Also, can you clarify what you mean by $X>\alpha$? This doesn't make sense to me, because $X$ is a random variable. You can talk about the expectation of a random variable being above or below a threshold, $<X> > \alpha$, or the probability of a random variable being above a threshold $\rm{Pr}(X > \alpha) > 0.1$, say, but what you've written doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: >>Also, can you clarify what you mean by X>α?                          I want to calculate the expected value of the sum S. There are no expected values inside the sum. We don't count variables less than $X<\alpha$ that can be represented as $<\sum_{i=0}^N \theta (X_i-\alpha) X_i>$. The sum can be calculated explicitly by using Poisson pmf for $X_i$.  $<S>=<\sum_{i=0}^N \theta (X_i-\alpha) X_i>=\sum_{i=0}^N \sum_{k=0}^\infty \theta (k-\alpha) k \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$. The hard question for me is how to formalize the second condition.

Comment: i believe that @Did's result is the correct one. I just want to double check it numerically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S_n$ denote the expected value based on an array of size $n\geqslant1$ and $S_n=0$ for every $n\leqslant0$. Let $m=E[X\mid X\gt\alpha]$. Let $T$ the time of the first success in an i.i.d. sequence with probability of success $p=P[X\gt\alpha]$ hence $P[T=i]=pq^{i-1}$ for every $i\geqslant1$, where $q=1-p$. Then, for every $n$,
$$
S_n=mP[T\leqslant n]+\sum_{i\geqslant1}P[T=i]\,S_{n-i-k}.
$$
Thus, $S_n=mP[T\leqslant n]=m(1-q^n)$ for every $n\leqslant k+1$. Consider the series
$$
s(x)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}S_nx^n,\qquad t(x)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}P[T=n]x^n,\qquad t_1(x)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}P[T\leqslant n]x^n.
$$
The recursion above translates into
$$
s(x)=mt_1(x)+x^ks(x)t(x).
$$
Since $t_1(x)=t(x)/(1-x)$, this yields
$$
s(x)=\frac{mt(x)}{(1-x)(1-x^kt(x))}.
$$
Since $t(x)=px/(1-qx)$, one gets
$$
s(x)=\frac{mpx}{(1-x)(1-qx-px^{k+1})}=\frac{mpx}{(1-x)^2D(x)},
$$
with $D(x)=1+px+px^2+\cdots+px^k$.
When $|x|\lt1$, $|qx+px^{k+1}|\lt q+p=1$ hence $1-qx-px^{k+1}\ne0$. Thus, $D(x)$ has no root $x$ such that $|x|\leqslant1$. Finally, when $n\to\infty$,
$$
\frac{S_n}n\to\frac{mp}{D(1)}=\frac{m}{k+p^{-1}}.
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{S_n}n\to\frac{mp}{D(1)}$?

Comment: Under mild conditions (met here), $(1-x)^2s(x)\to\ell$ when $x\to1$ and $S_n/n\to\ell$ when $n\to\infty$ are equivalent. These are called Tauberian theorems.